# Massive Gap in listview after uploading .txt file (C#)

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I'm still too new to show what my listview looks like, but here is the code:

```
    private void openClientFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog OF = new OpenFileDialog();
            OF.ShowDialog(this);
            OF.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            OF.RestoreDirectory = true;
            string file = OF.FileName;


            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);

            listView1.Items.Clear();

           foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(file))
           {
               ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

                   lvi.Text = sr.ReadLine(); 

                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   lvi.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                   listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
           }
           sr.Dispose();
        }
                catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

So here's the problem, I upload the file and it places my items exactly where they should go... Except its 7 lines down from the beginning of the listview and I don't know why.

However... If I comment out the line of code that says

```
    lvi.Text = sr.ReadLine();
```

The huge gap is gone, however the first column is skipped completely which wont work either. What am I doing wrong?

(Also there aren't any gaps in the .txt file that I am trying to load into listview.)

Comment: Can u paste a screenshot?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that :/

Comment: you dont need 2 file read mechanisms sr.ReadLine(); reads a line and  File.ReadLines(file) reads all the lines into an array which is never used from the looks of it

Comment: Yikes that's embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out. I switched out readline for line and the gap is gone. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too clear why you are doing both File.ReadLine as well as StreamReader.ReadLine. But this is the cause of your error. You can do this to rectify it.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i= i + 8)
       {
           ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

               lvi.Text = line[i]; 

               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+1]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+2]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+3]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+4]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+5]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+6]);
               lvi.SubItems.Add(line[i+7]);
               listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
       }
```

You will need error handling to make this fool proof.

Comment: This looks like it should work but for some reason I am getting the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" but you have it to where it should line up in just the right spot. So I have no idea why this isn't working

Comment: Ah, turns out I had too many subitems coded in. This works perfectly! Sorry I am a noob lmao. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: It is because the loop assumes that your file has multiples of 8 lines i.e. 16, 24